# how to turn URL to the new domain?

Tags: apache, nginx

old domain link:

```
http://www.old.com/aa/bb/cc.html
```

i want when this old link to be visiting,turn to:

```
http://www.new.com/aa/bb/cc.html
```

how to do this?

BTW: nginx or apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file similar to the following and place it to the old domain root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

For nginx I go with this on account that it also helps with alias domains.

```
if ($host != 'www.new.com' ) {
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://www.new.com/$1 permanent;
}
```